# How to insert a list of name in a c++ program like we insert an integers in an int array

Tags: multidimensional-array

I am writing

Char name [5][4];

For(i=1;i<4;i++)
Cin>>name[5][i];

But it is showing error

Comment: _"it is showing error"_ **What** error?

Comment: Btw, c++ is case sensitive. Also, you have an out-of-bounds error where you try to access `name[5]` (array indexing is 0-based, so index 5 means the 6th element). And c++ has a perfectly good `std::string` type, so you don't have to use raw char arrays.